# Create Calendar Event, Failure on Form Submit

Tags: api, events, calendar, google-calendar-api

I have the code below which I have written and on Form Submit, will create a calendar event to the parameters. However I always get a failure that comes back via email:

TypeError: Cannot find function createEvent in object Calendar. (line 59, file "Create Event"). It's failing to find the Calendar, I have tried this by CalendarID and CalendarName.

Any assistance would be grateful.

```js
function CreateEvent(e) {

  var Group = e.values[1];
  var startTime = e.values[2];
  var endTime = e.values[3];
  var Activitytitle = e.values[4];
  var Actlocation = e.values[5];
  var ActivityDesc = e.values[6];
  var AuthLeader = e.values[7];
  var AuthLeaderNo = e.values[8];
  var AuthLeaderPermit = e.values[9];
  var LeaderCharge = e.values[10];
  var LeaderChargeNo = e.values[11];
  var LeaderEmail = e.values[12];
  var Adults = e.values[13];
  var Beavers = e.values[14];
  var Cubs = e.values[15];
  var Scouts = e.values[16];
  var Explorers = e.values[17];
  var Other = e.values[18];
  var InTouchName = e.values[19];
  var InTouchContact = e.values[20];
  var ManagerEmail = e.values[21];
  var RA = e.values[22];
  var Rules = e.values[23];
  
  var title = "(Pending) " + Activitytitle;
  
  var Actdescription = "<h2>Activity Information</h2>" +
  "<b>Group:</b> "  + Group + " <br/>" +
  "<b>Type of Activity:</b> " + Activitytitle + " <br/>" +
  "<b>Activity Date Start:</b> " + startTime + " <br/>" +
  "<b>Activity Date End:</b> " + endTime + " <br/>" + " <br/>" +
  "<b>Location:</b> " + Actlocation + " <br/>" +
  "<b>Brief Description of Activity:</b> " + ActivityDesc + " <br/>" + " <br/>" +
  "<h2>Adventurous Activities Permit Information</h2>" +
  "<b>Authorised Leader:</b> " + AuthLeader +" <br/>" +
  "<b>Authorised Leader Contact Number:</b> " + AuthLeaderNo + " <br/>" +
  "<b>Permit Details:</b> " + AuthLeaderPermit + " <br/>" + " <br/>" +
  "<h2>Attendance Details</h2>" +
  "<b>Leader in Charge:</b> " + LeaderCharge + " <br/>" +
  "<b>Leader Contact Number:</b> " + LeaderChargeNo + " <br/>" +
  "<b>Leader Email</b>: " + LeaderEmail + " <br/>" + " <br/>" +
  "<b>Number of Adults (18+):</b> " + Adults + " <br/>" +
  "<b>Non Uniform YP (Under 18):</b> " + Other + " <br/>" +
  "<b>Number of Beavers:</b> " + Beavers + " <br/>" +
  "<b>Number of Cubs:</b> " + Cubs + " <br/>" +
  "<b>Number of Scouts:</b> " + Scouts + " <br/>" +
  "<b>Number of Explorers/Young Leaders:</b> " + Explorers + " <br/>" + " <br/>" +
  "<h2>Health and Safety Information</h2>" +
  "<b>Line Managers Email Address:</b> " + ManagerEmail + " <br/>" + " <br/>" +
  "<b>InTouch Contact:</b> " + InTouchName + " <br/>" +
  "<b>InTouch Contact Number:</b> " + InTouchContact + " <br/>" + " <br/>" +
  "<b>Risk Assessment Completed:</b> " + RA + " <br/>" +
  "<b>Scout Association POR Guidelines Followed:</b> " + Rules;
  
  var myCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName('Activity Notifications');
  Logger.log('Found %s matching calendars.', calendars.length);
  
  myCal.createEvent (title, startTime, endTime, {
    description : Actdescription,
    location : Actlocation
  });
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using AppScript, [`CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-app#getCalendarsByName(String)) returns a [`Calendar[]`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar) array and that's the reason of it failing. Find the appropriate Calendar in the array and then promptly call the `createEvent` method with it.

Comment: I have amended the code, to an example from Google Class Developers website. I am still getting a failure notice. Now the failure is Line 58 (The logger).

I have now also added the True Calendar Name.

Sorry I am not an experienced coder.

Comment: `calendars` is undefined (which is most likely the error your getting). Use `myCal.length`. For the `createEvent` line, either try to loop or if you know the array isn't empty, call `myCal[0].createEvent(...)`

Comment: Could you give me an example, I can't seem to find one on the net.